# On Flajolet's analytic urn model: a unified approach or just an interesting trick?

Tags: pr.probability

Recently I'm reading Flajolet's work on analytic urn models. In around 2006 He introduced a new analytical method that can give exact solutions to many classical urn models in a unified way. For a balanced urn model, he associated it with a system of PDEs of which the solutions can give the generating function of the urn model very quickly, which is very interesting. This is part of his work that I can understand, and there are a lot more in his work that I can not understand.

My question is, does Flajolet's analytic method have more applications than merely help us calculating the probability distributions of the urn (at any time)? Are there anything that cannot be done without his analytic way?